# passing unicode strings from django to javascript

Tags: javascript, python, django, unicode

I have a bunch of unicode strings in my data which I need to pass from my django view to template for using in a JavaScript scriptlet that passes it to the web back and forth.

The problem is I want the strings to be represented in the JavaScript unicode form but I get strings with a **u** prefix from python.

For example, for the string **mężczyźni**, Python stores it as **u'm\u0119\u017cczy\u017ani'** but when it is passed to the template, it *does not* remove the **u** prefix which creates problems for JavaScript while processing it. I want it to be simply **'m\u0119\u017cczy\u017ani'** so that the JavaScript code in the template can use it.

I tried using urqluote, smart_unicode, force_unicode but couldn't hit a solution or even a hack.

What do I do ?

Comment: Did you try [`escapejs`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/?from=olddocs#escapejs)

Comment: Please show your view and template code.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid, using `escapejs` resulted in converting the single quotes also. But that was a  good hint. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Edit:** Django 1.7+ [no longer includes simplejson](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/releases/1.7/#features-removed-in-1-7). Instead of

```
from django.utils import simplejson
```

write

```
import json
```

and then use `json` instead of `simplejson`.

---

You are probably printing the python repr of your data dict, and trying to parse it in javascript:

```
{{ your_python_data }}
```

Instead, you could export your data in json:

```
from django.utils import simplejson

json_data_string = simplejson.dumps(your_data)
```

And load the data directly in javascript:

```
var your_data = {{ json_data_string }};
```

You could also make a [template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#):

```
from django.utils import simplejson
from django import template
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

register = template.Library()


@register.filter
def as_json(data):
    return mark_safe(simplejson.dumps(data))
```

And in your template:

```
{% load your_template_tags %}

{{ your_python_data|as_json }}
```

Note that you should be careful with XSS, if some of "data" comes from user input, then you should sanitize it.

Comment: Thanks @jpic That worked. I just had to add a *safe* filter to render it properly.                                                  So now, my code looks like this: `{{ your_python_data|as_json|safe }}`

Comment: Apparently, simpleJson is deprecated. Do you know what replaced it?

Comment: the native json module

Comment: On django 1.7+ simplejson is not included any more. Instead use the `json` - module. I will suggest an edit.